# Swift lldb - Convert int to string

Tags: swift

I'm very basic to Swift and trying to convert a text value, multiply its value by 7 and print the output.

WHen I try to print the output I get "lldb"?

Why do I get this error?

```
@IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(age.text!)

    let enteredAge = Int(age.text!)


    let catYears = enteredAge! * 7

    print(String(catYears))


}
```

Comment: What error message is shown just above the "lldb" prompt? BTW - that's the debugger prompt since your app just crashed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: By the way, you are converting a string to an int. The title is misleading :-)

Comment: @rmaddy:There is no msg shown above the "lldb".

Comment: You should still read through the question and answers I linked. You will learn a lot of very important information. Your code is full of likely crashes due to all the misuses of the `!` operator.

Comment: Try using `print("\(catYears)")`

Comment: just use nil coalescing operator to unwrap and set a default value in case of invalid string is entered `let enteredAge = Int(age.text ?? "") ?? 0` and `let catYears  = enteredAge * 7`

Comment: Is the "text value", a string taken from a `UITextField`? Or is this an arbitrary `String` text?

Comment: @KSigWyatt "text value" it is the age UITextField text field property which return an optional String so you need to unwrap it also prior to converting it to integer.

Answer (score -2):

You should be checking if it can actually be converted to an Integer.

```
let enteredAge = Int(age.text!)
if enteredAge == nil{
    //do nothing
}
else{
    //multiply by 7
}
```

Comment: Yes, you should be checking but this is not a good way to do it.

Comment: What would be better, just to help him get an answer @rmaddy

Comment: `if let text = age.text, let enteredAge = Int(text) {  let catYears = enteredAge * 7 }`